# Can these serve as ties to home Country for Canada TRV?

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, nigerian-citizens

I have this concern.
I was denied visas to canada twice on grounds that i was not going to return based on travel history. I was not married then, and I did not have travel history. I had a good job.

Now things changed I have some upgrades, now i want to try Canada once more.

- I have since been to 2 Neighbouring Countries here in West Africa, Have the stamps in my international Passport
- I am Married, Just got married (No child)
- I have a job here in Nigeria (I work in a financial Institution)
- I have a small business of Real Estate
- I have some properties handed over to me by my Father. (Landed Properties, houses etc)

Now I have a Question, Can these serve as a tie or ties to home country? I need advices here

Comment: How recent were the denials?

Comment: @Traveller, Earlier this year. I have not applied again since then

Comment: What do you want to do in Canada? Entry now is pretty restricted whatever our ties.

Comment: don't waste an attempt at getting a visa now - the border is closed to non essential travel and will be for some time. When the pandemic is over you will have been married, employed, a landowner and whatnot for a lot longer than you have been now. In the meantime keep building a travel history in places that haven't closed their borders because of covid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time due to Covid19 you can only visit Canada for essential travel.

In general, all the things you list will improve your chances of getting a temporary visa to Canada. In particular having a job will be a substantial improvement (if you did not previously have a job).

It is impossible to say if the changes will be enough to get you a visa. It will depend on other circumstances apart from ties to your home country, including your financial circumstances and your reason for visiting. Also your previous refusals will be taken into account.

The most significant additional improvement would be to visit countries that you need a visa for, ideally ones similar to Canada in terms of immigration restrictions.

You should beware of making repeated applications after refusal. They show an attitude of "get to Canada at all costs" which is itself a red flag and will reduce your chances.